# Magento 2: How to get ordered item details from order collection?

Tags: magento2, product, orders, order-collection

I have successfully got the order details and below is my code to get the details. Now, I need to get the ordered item details. Please guide

```
$collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/307582

Comment: please check and update me. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/329141/82670

Answer (score 3):

> **Try this code**

```
protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
    ......................................
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    ......................................
) {
    ......................................
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    ......................................
}

public function getAllOrderProducts()
{
    $orderCollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $orderData = $orderCollection->getData();
    if (count($orderCollection->getData())) {
        if (isset($orderData[0])) {
            foreach ($orderData as $attribute) {
                $order_id = $attribute['entity_id'];
                $order_data = $this->orderRepository->get($order_id);
                if (!empty($order_data)) {
                    foreach ($order_data->getAllItems() as $value) {
                        print_r($value->debug());
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $order_id = $orderData['entity_id'];
            $order_data = $this->orderRepository->get($order_id);
            if (!empty($order_data)) {
                foreach ($order_data->getAllItems() as $value) {
                    print_r($value->debug());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below code for get ordered item details :

```
$collection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*'); // It returns all order collection
        foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value->getAllItems() as $key1 => $items) {
                echo $items->getName() . "<br/>";
                echo $items->getPrice() . "<br/>";
                echo $items->getSku() . "<br/>";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($collection as $order) {
            foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                echo $item->getName();
                echo $item->getQtyOrdered();
                ..............
                ..............
            }
```